# PHP path to file not found

Tags: php, path, include

this is a part of a script I wrote:

```
$rslt = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$include = 'mod/' . $rslt['module'] . '/main.php';
$content = include($include);
```

var_dump()ing $include tells me the following:

> string(18) "mod/paste/main.php"

But never the less, PHP outputs:

> include(mod//main.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...

I don't know how to fix this problem.
Thank you for your help,

Lukas ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The script was called twice because Chrome wants to display a favicon.ico. Because of my .htaccess file this request was also forwarded to the script.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Go ahead and set your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to double check that `$rslt['module']` exists reliably (try and find any scenarios where it wouldn't contain a value). looks like whenever you var_dump'd the value, that value was set, otherwise it doesn't appear to be.

you may also want to turn on error reporting. if that array element isnt set, you should be getting errors when trying to access it.

check your php.ini file for a line `display_errors`

Comment: error_reporting and display_errors don't tell me anything. The error is still the same. var_dump'ing befor and after the use of $rslt like this: 
`var_dump($rslt);
            $include = 'mod/' . $rslt['module'] . '/main.php';
            var_dump($rslt);`

tells me this: 
`array(2) { ["module"]=> string(5) "paste" ["value"]=> string(2) "36" } array(2) { ["module"]=> string(5) "paste" ["value"]=> string(2) "36" }`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing one of the / behind mod